# Жизненный цикл фрагментов

Tags: android

В общем,ситуация такая. Существует активити А, на которой есть фрагменты А,В и С. В приложении существует возможность логиниться и разлогиниваться. Если пользователь в момент, когда надумал разлогиниться, находится на фрагменте В, то когда он опять залогинится, то будет на том же фрагменте В. Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы пользователь после повторного захода в приложение попадал на фрагмент А, а не на тот фрагмент, на котором он был в момент разлогинивания?

Comment: фокус сменить?

Comment: ну что-то вроде этого;нужно,чтобы когда логинишься,то попадаешь сразу на фрагмент А стартового активити

Answer (score 1, accepted):

После удачной авторизации попробуй

```
frag1.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
frag1.requestFocus();
```

Comment: почему-то эти методы у меня не вызываются

Comment: вызови их не на фрагментах, а на элементы, которые на них

Comment: увы,не помогло;может как-то можно чистить(или какое-нибудь другое со стеком) стек фрагментов после удачной авторизации?

Comment: getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this).commit();

Comment: ну так передай ему имяФрагмента.this

Comment: да я просто передал имя фрагмента,компилятор ругаться перестал,но эффекта всё равно никакого